# Powershell script to replace --secret-keyring to sign and encrypt file

Tags: powershell, encryption, gnupg

Im really struggling with this, as Ive been trying to find solutions as Im getting frustrated. Id be really grateful if someone can advise. I'd be much appreciated as I'm new to powershell.

Here is the part of the code that I need help with:

```
foreach ($item in $items)
        {
        #if the item name contains date, then process it.
        if ($item.FullName -like "*.txt")
        {
        #Write-Host $item.FullName
        set-alias gpg2 "C:\Program Files (x86)\GnuPG\bin\gpg.exe"                    
        gpg2 --default-key "test@uat.co.uk" --pinentry-mode loopback --batch --yes --passphrase-file="D:\AutomatedJobs\abc\def\Cred\PGP-Creds.txt" --keyring "C:\Users\svc.xxx\AppData\Roaming\gnupg\pubring.kbx" --secret-keyring "C:\Users\svc.xxx\AppData\Roaming\gnupg\pubring.kbx" --log-file "D:\AutomatedJobs\abc\def\Logs\Sign-$(get-date -f yyyyMMdd).log" --verbose --force-mdc --trust-model always --output "$item.asc" --sign $item.FullName  
        Remove-Item $item.FullName
        }
    }
```

Im using this on Windows Server 2016, it's working fine. Though its Task Scheduler that trigger the ps1 script. I need to setup the same job in Windows Server 2019. However, when Im trying to run, command --secret-keyring stated that its obsolete and ignore. Log stated that no default key found. The job actually trigger Kleopatra GPG to sign and encrypt file. I need this to happen before the file can be transferred. My question is - based on above script what is the replacement for --secret-keyring so that the file can be signed and encrypted. I'd really appreciate if someone can help.

I've run the script to point to private key in this location - 'private-keys-v1.d’ but didn't work.

Comment: Not sure what is obsolete.  GPG looks like it is still supported so I think the encryption algorithm you are using is old.  See following which may help : https://docs.github.com/en/authentication/managing-commit-signature-verification/generating-a-new-gpg-key

Comment: Thanks for your reply jdweng. The error prompted: gpg2: gpg: WARNING: "--secret-keyring" is an obsolete option - it has no effect. Due to this, I feel that Kleopatra unable to 'sign' the file using the default private key

Comment: You need to use Private keys which replace secrete-keying.  Kleopatra GPG manages certificate.  So your private key is in a certificate.  You need to install the certificate.  Certificates are used for many purposes.  Following is for SSL but will work for other purposes : https://help.fasthosts.co.uk/app/answers/detail/a_id/2031/~/installing-an-ssl-certificate-using-windows-server-2019%2C-2016-or-2012?force_isolation=true

Comment: Yes, the certificates already imported and installed. The job run required Powershell script not to ignore secret keyring. Im looking for alternative, so signing via powershell script is successful.

Comment: There is no need to use secret keying, the info is in the certificate. What happens if you just remove the secret keying?  Is the private key the name in the certificate?